# Apt doesn’t seem to update package sources when attempting to install Mono on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mono-framework

I’m currently tinkering with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a virtual machine. I have been having success with getting my Samba server set up correctly and I have also set up my FTP service. So the next thing I wanted to add was an Apache server with ASP.NET support and this is where I got stuck:

First of all I tried installing [Mono 3.2.8](http://www.mono-project.com) but while installing that I found that since then some improvements have been made to Mono that I’d like to have. So I uninstalled Mono—using `apt-get remove mono-runtime`, `apt-get autoremove`—and started setting up the official repositories for Mono so I could install Xamarins Mono 3.12:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Which seems to have succeeded. However then I installed mono using:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Which resulted in apt installing Ubuntu’s Mono 3.2.8 instead of Xamarins Mono 3.12 which I was expecting.

```
sudo apt-cache show mono-complete
```

Only shows the 3.2.8 version from the Ubuntu repositories. I’m not sure where I messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [official Mono project Ubuntu install instructions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/), it looks like you are skipping a step; emphasis is mine:

> To enable `mod_mono` installation on Ubuntu 13.10 and later, and Debian
>   8.0 and later (and their derivatives), **you will need to add a second repository to your system, in addition to the generic Debian/Ubuntu
>   repository above** (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):

The instructions you are showing only shows the second additional repository for the Apache `mod_mono` module; not the core Mono install. So you also need to run this command:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

The run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

And you should be good.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Thanks a lot. Dammit, they even put "in addition" in bold letters and I missed that. -.-

Comment: Cannot vote up because I don't have the necessary reputation. Sorry.